# nats.io python client does not flush on close

Tags: python, nats.io

I have a leetle test program which does not work unless I do a `client.flush()` before `client.close()`. A naive reading of [nats/aio/client.py](https://github.com/nats-io/asyncio-nats/blob/master/nats/aio/client.py#L217) seems to suggest that `close()` does some kind of `flush()`, so I do not understand why my test program fails. Is it necessary to always `flush()` before `close()`? Example programs don't seem to indicate so.

I can see that `close()` calls `_flush_pending()`, but this does something quite different from `flush()`:

- `flush()` calls `_send_ping()` to send a `PING` and waits for a `PONG` response. `_send_ping()` writes directly to `self._io_writer`, and then calls `_flush_pending()`.
- `_flush_pending()` pushes a None (anything will do, I guess) into `self._flush_queue`. This presumably wakes the `_flusher()` and causes it to write everything in `self._pending` to `self._io_writer`.
- `publish()` calls `_send_command()` to push the messages onto `self._pending`, and then also calls `_flush_pending()` to cause the `_flusher()` to write everything.

The test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import asyncio
import nats.aio.client
import nats.aio.errors

async def send_message(loop):
    mq_url = "nats://nats:password@127.0.0.1:4222"
    client = nats.aio.client.Client()
    await client.connect(io_loop=loop, servers=[mq_url])
    await client.publish("test_subject", "test1".encode())
    #await client.flush()
    await client.close()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(send_message(loop))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

FWIW if I send a large number of messages then, at some point (haven't yet worked out the exact conditions), messages are sent. We noticed the behaviour when processing a collection of files and sending a message for each line in the file: some files were making it through, others weren't, and it turned out it was the larger files (more lines) that made it. So it looks as though some internal buffer is filled and this forces a flush.

Comment: Have you tried not exiting your program immediately after the close?

Comment: I added `await asyncio.sleep(5)` after `client.close()`. The program runs for 5s (so it is clearly waiting), but the result is the same: no message sent to nats.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like was probably a bug which has just been fixed: https://github.com/nats-io/asyncio-nats/pull/35